Find all solutions of $2f(x)f(y)＝f(x+y)+f(x-y)$
We know that when $f(x)$ is continuous, the only solutions are $f(x)=\cos(ax)$, $f(x)=\cosh(ax)$, $f(x)≡0$, and $f(x)≡1$. When $f(x)$ is non-continuous, the existence can be proved as follows.

Proof:
Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the linear space over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}$. For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exist finite coefficients $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_N \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that
$$x = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \lambda_i x_i.$$
Define
$$h(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \lambda_i h(x_i);$$
where $h(t), t \in \mathcal{B}$ can be arbitrarily chosen. Let $g(x) = h(x) + x$. It can be verified that $g(x)$ satisfies the functional equation
$$g(x+y) = g(x) + g(y).$$
In most points, the function
$$f(x) = \cosh g(x) = \cosh(h(x) + x)$$
$$f(x) = \cos g(x) = \cos(h(x) + x)$$
are not continuous.
I wonder its uniqueness:

In the case where $f(x)$ is non-continuous, whether the function $f(x)$ that satisfies the equation $2f(x)f(y) = f(x+y) + f(x-y)$ must necessarily be expressible in the following form: $f(x) = \cosh(g(x))$ or $f(x) = \cos(g(x))$, where $g(x+y) = g(x) + g(y)$?
Can every solution to the Cauchy equation be constructed using Hamel bases?
Is $g(x) = h(x) + x$ the unique solution to $g(x)$?

Edit 1:
It seems difficult to find all solutions (comments have shown that). Maybe a restriction is helpful:
$∀x, -1 < f(x) < 1$ (thus cos) or $∀x, f(x) > 1$ (thus cosh).

@Abezhiko Sorry, I forgot the trivial cases : )


I think you missed, for the continuous case, the solutions f(x) = cos(ax) and f(x) = cosh(ax) where a is a constant.
Point 1 is false as f(x)=cos(x) cannot be expressed as f(x)=cosh(g(x)+x), since this last expression doesn't take any negative values (if you desire a truly non-continuous example, take the map f(x) = cos(h(x)+x) with the h you defined). I don't think we can say that f(x) is either of the form cos(g(x)+x) or cos(g(x)+x) as it may be a mix of both (cosh on part of the basis, cos on another part of the basis for example), or something even worse...


For point 2. : all solutions of the Cauchy functional equation are $\mathbb{Q}$-linear, so all such solutions determine and are uniquely determined by their image on a Hamel basis, thus you can say that every solution is "constructed using Hamel bases", yes.

@MathMax I've editted the question by your suggestion. Now we can consider both $f(x)=cosh(g(x))$ and $f(x)=cos(g(x))$. You referred to "a mix of both, let $\cosh$ on part of the basis, $\cos$ on another part of the basis for example", I think it is really interesting. May I ask you turn the comment into an answer with details?

@BrunoB Thanks indeed! I should learn more on foundations of Real and Abstract Analysis (GTM25) .

Is it possible $|f(x_1)| < 1$ and $f(x_2) > 1$?

@aschepler I did not limit that. If it is rather difficult to reach a conclusion in this case, just "$\forall x, -1<f(x)<1$ (thus $\cos$)" or "$\forall x, f(x)>1$ (thus $\cosh$)".

In fact, I do not want to avoid any case even if it is difficult, that is, what my title has it "find all solution".

Yeah, I don't know the answer, and it relates to the "mix of both" thought by @MathMax. It may be that $h$ can specify some values less than $1$ and some greater than $1$ and we get a valid $f$. Or maybe the functional equation can't be satisfied on the vector space $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,x_2]$ and so all solutions do have either $|f(x)| \leq 1$ everywhere or $f(x) \geq 1$ everywhere. ($\leq$ instead of $<$ because interesting solutions must have $f(0)=1$.)

@aschepler I add the restriction to the question, thanks!

Okay, though I think it's more interesting without the restriction.
